# Fusion of neuron with a S phase cell

Tags: cell-biology, mitosis

There was some experiment in which a S phase cell was fused with other cell and the other cell also began to replicate DNA. Would the same happen if fused with nerve cell ? Why or why not?

Comment: fusing cells is not feasible in all cases (it also causes polyploidy).. cells are immortalized by using oncogenes..

Comment: you can also look at [this](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10301/is-forced-cell-growth-related-to-apoptosis/10302#10302) post

Comment: Just an addition to the WYSIWYG's answer: phenomenon of neuronal de-differentiation under the influence of oncogenes [was shown](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23087000).

Answer (score 2):

This specific experiment has not been done. Fusing cells is difficult and it also leads to polyploidy. Cells are immortalized by overexpressing oncogenes (or viral replication genes); for example HEK293 cell line was established by transforming embryonic kidney cells with adenovirus.

Now transforming a neuron would immortalize it but would also make it lose its function; for a cell like neuron, replication would compromise its activity for e.g. loss of established synapses. As mentioned in the comments by har-wradim, it [was shown](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23087000) that transforming neurons with oncogenes leads to their de-differentiation. Another experiment of transforming neurons gave a contrasting result. [Feddersen et al](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/089662739290247B) transformed purkinje cells in mice by expressing SV40 viral t-antigen from a purkinje-cell specific promoter and surprisingly it lead to degeneration of cerebellar tissue. Also have a look at [this](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/24/42/9232.full) article.